# Python Pandas Merge Key Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Why does the following fail with KeyError 'NUM'?

```
result = pandas.merge(sdf_subset, dfgeom, how='inner', on=['ID', 'NUM'])
```

The column 'ID' exists in sdf_subset and 'NUM' exists in dfgeom. I have checked the datatype and both are Int64.

Any ideas?

Comment: check if the column names have spaces, what does `sdf_subset.columns.tolist()` and `dfgeom.columns.tolist()` show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# you need to use left_on and right_on if the joining key is different between the dataframes.
result = pandas.merge(sdf_subset, dfgeom, how='inner', left_on='ID', right_on='NUM')
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helps.